# refresh parent page on button click in usercontrol asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net c#
I have a page with just a `Label`, `Button`

A user control with a `Textbox` and `Button`. 
I want to attach the value of `Textbox` to the main pages `Label` it is working fine.
 But I want to refresh the main page from usercontrols Button but also I don't want to lose entered data on main page.

Comment: why do you want to refresh the main page? Or do you want to reset the data?

Comment: to attach the data entered in textbox

Comment: you can you javascript or jquery for this don't need refresh or something. Also try to use .net core web application rather than asp.net.

Comment: i want to refresh page on closing event of that panel

Comment: or how can i show the text entered in label on closing poup

Comment: it is showing now but i have to manually refresh the page then it is showing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.